# UICollectionView: Do I need to use an UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am using XCode5 and iOS7. 
Is it possible to embed a UICollectionView into a normal UIViewController class and have the UIViewController implement the  methods?

Or do I need the UICollectionViewController?

Which methods are required at minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to implement UICollectionView without UICollectionViewController. CollectionViews are just like tableView.

As you probably already know, when you use a UITableView you have to set a data source and a delegate in order to provide the data to display and handle events (like row selection).
Similarly, when you use a UICollectionView you have to set a data source and a delegate as well. 
Their roles are the following:
1. The data source **(UICollectionViewDataSource)** returns information about the number of items in the collection view and their views.
2. The delegate **(UICollectionViewDelegate)** is notified when events happen such as cells being selected, highlighted, or removed.

And new to UICollectionView, you have a third protocol you must implement – a protocol specific to the **layout manager** you are using for the collection view.

Comment: But I can use the standard UICollectionViewFlowLayout without subclassing?

Comment: If you want to take advantage of the built in cell drag-and-drop functionality, you have to use a subclass of UICollectionViewController so you can set the installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement property to true.  Otherwise if you want drag-and-drop when using UICollectionView without UICollectionViewController, you have to implement the gesture recognizer yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UICollectionView, you'll need the UICollectionView to conform to the UICollectionViewDelegate and  UICollectionViewDataSource protocols.

so you will need at a minimum;

numberOfSectionsInCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection and you'll need to implement cellForItemAtIndexPath to create the cells. Obviously you'll also need to define the Cell

Comment: I understand... that was my understanding, though I haven't found any tutorial w/o UICollectionVieController...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an UICollectionViewController. Just make sure, that your ViewController implements the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`.

This example should help you with the topic UICollectionView:
http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Answer is NO. **UICollectionView** is subclass of **UIVIew** and can be added to any view you wish.
Since **UIVIewController** has view property you can add **UICollectionView** to it using:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

Here is a great tutorial with sample project where you can see how to implement **UICollectionView** in your custom **UIViewController** subclass:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: tx for the hint...I don't see your link to the sample...?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste it, check the edited answer :)